# Check if flash movie is executable or embedded

Tags: actionscript-3, embed, executable

I'm building an interactive menu that will either be executed as an executable file (redundancy, yeah) in windows, or will be embedded on a webpage on mac. Is there any way to compare the `root.parent` object to check if it's an executable or a webpage embed stage kind of object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can request the player type with [**flash.system.Capabilities.playerType**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#playerType)

> Specifies the type of runtime environment. This property can have one
>   of the following values:
>
> - "ActiveX" for the Flash Player ActiveX control used by Microsoft Internet Explorer
> - "Desktop" for the Adobe AIR runtime
> - "External" for the external Flash Player or in test mode
> - "PlugIn" for the Flash Player browser plug-in
> - "StandAlone" for the stand-alone Flash Player

However, I need to ask:  Why are you aiming for a separate UX on different platforms?

Comment: I just noticed the last question, and since i asked mine, I didn't know projector files could be exported for Mac as well. I was intending to open the exe file on autorun from Windows, and embedding it on a html file on mac. Is there any way i can recognize from inside the flash movie wether it is an executable projector or an app projector?

Comment: Nevermind, i just discovered hybrid discs, so no need for that. Sort of a Mac n00b here. Thanks!

Comment: Why not publish a cross platform AIR application?

Comment: Wouldn't I require to install AIR on the computers I try to run the menu? The idea is to be able to run the menu out of the box in any mac or pc environment

Comment: During installation, your application will install AIR on the deployment target if it's missing.  However, you can also create an AIR Captive Runtime, which doesn't require users to install AIR separately since it's bundled with your application.  There are benifits and drawbacks to using AIR Captive Runtime   `http://goo.gl/1uoMM`, but it's becomming standard.  Previously, developers using AIR had the option to use Shared or Captive Runtime when targeting Android, but since AIR 3.7, AIR Android applications require Captive (or Embedded) Runtime, just like it's always been with iOS deployment.